# Ubuntu Mate 16.04 - VirtualboxGuest Overheating

Tags: virtualbox, firefox, java, mate, overheating

I have a virtualbox guest installed with ubuntu mate.
This host is overheating my laptop since some day, specially when browsing with firefox (with chromium less) or using java apps (i.e. eclipse).

```
top
```

is confirming the high cpu usage.

I tried many posts suggestions, but without sensible result:

- optimizing virtualbox settings
- changing the windoe render: marco -> compiz -> marco compton
- reinstalling java with complete clean: openJDK -> java -> openJDK
- updating / purging / autocleaning
- cleaning firefox profile, starting in safe mode
- ...

Now I am short of options. This is the hw configuration from

```
sudo lshw -sanitize
```

Hope it could help, you'll see that I assigned only 2 cpu over 8, but nothing is changing with 4 or 6:

```
computer                  
    description: Computer
    product: VirtualBox
    vendor: innotek GmbH
    version: 1.2
    serial: [REMOVED]
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.5 dmi-2.5 vsyscall32
    configuration: family=Virtual Machine uuid=[REMOVED]
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: VirtualBox
       vendor: Oracle Corporation
       physical id: 0
       version: 1.2
       serial: [REMOVED]
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: innotek GmbH
          physical id: 0
          version: VirtualBox
          date: 12/01/2006
          size: 128KiB
          capabilities: isa pci cdboot bootselect int9keyboard int10video acpi
     *-memory
          description: System memory
          physical id: 1
          size: 3945MiB
     *-cpu
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6440HQ CPU @ 2.60GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 2
          bus info: cpu@0
          width: 64 bits
          capabilities: fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid pni ssse3 pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic hypervisor lahf_lm invpcid_single pti retpoline rsb_ctxsw fsgsbase invpcid
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma]
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 02
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
        *-ide
             description: IDE interface
             product: 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: ide bus_master
             configuration: driver=ata_piix latency=64
             resources: irq:0 ioport:1f0(size=8) ioport:3f6 ioport:170(size=8) ioport:376 ioport:d000(size=16)
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: VirtualBox Graphics Adapter
             vendor: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: vga_controller rom
             configuration: driver=vboxvideo latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:e0000000-e7ffffff memory:c0000-dffff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
             logical name: enp0s3
             version: 02
             serial: [REMOVED]
             size: 1Gbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=[REMOVED] latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
             resources: irq:19 memory:f0000000-f001ffff ioport:d010(size=8)
        *-generic
             description: System peripheral
             product: VirtualBox Guest Service
             vendor: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH
             physical id: 4
             bus info: pci@0000:00:04.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=vboxguest latency=0
             resources: irq:20 ioport:d020(size=32) memory:f0400000-f07fffff memory:f0800000-f0803fff
        *-multimedia
             description: Multimedia audio controller
             product: 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 5
             bus info: pci@0000:00:05.0
             version: 01
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master
             configuration: driver=snd_intel8x0 latency=64
             resources: irq:21 ioport:d100(size=256) ioport:d200(size=64)
        *-bridge
             description: Bridge
             product: 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 7
             bus info: pci@0000:00:07.0
             version: 08
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bridge
             configuration: driver=piix4_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:9
        *-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0c.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=64
             resources: irq:20 memory:f0810000-f081ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: Human interface device
                   product: USB Tablet
                   vendor: VirtualBox
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 1.00
                   capabilities: usb-1.10
                   configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.13.0-38-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.13
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=5000Mbit/s
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:0d.0
             version: 02
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: storage pm ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:21 ioport:d240(size=8) ioport:d248(size=4) ioport:d250(size=8) ioport:d258(size=4) ioport:d260(size=16) memory:f0820000-f0821fff
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 3
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD reader
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             capabilities: audio dvd
             configuration: status=nodisc
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 4
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: VBOX HARDDISK
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 1.0
             serial: [REMOVED]
             size: 78GiB (83GB)
             capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
             configuration: ansiversion=5 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512 signature=aea58258
           *-volume:0
                description: EXT4 volume
                vendor: Linux
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                logical name: /
                version: 1.0
                serial: [REMOVED]
                size: 74GiB
                capacity: 74GiB
                capabilities: primary bootable journaled extended_attributes large_files huge_files dir_nlink extents ext4 ext2 initialized
                configuration: created=2017-10-28 13:36:26 filesystem=ext4 lastmountpoint=/ modified=2018-04-05 08:01:44 mount.fstype=ext4 mount.options=rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,stripe=32606,data=ordered mounted=2018-04-04 17:23:34 state=mounted
           *-volume:1
                description: Extended partition
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                size: 4095MiB
                capacity: 4095MiB
                capabilities: primary extended partitioned partitioned:extended
              *-logicalvolume
                   description: Linux swap / Solaris partition
                   physical id: 5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   capacity: 4094MiB
                   capabilities: nofs
```

Comment: "I have a virtualbox guest installed with ubuntu mate. This host is overheating my laptop" The beginning is somewhat unclear.  Please edit your post in order to make it more clear

Comment: Sorry: host is windows10, guest is ubuntu mate. Guest is overheating as stated

Comment: Virtual machines should not be used for "CPU-hungry" software since it burdens your host even more. (CPU used by Windows and Ubuntu MATE VM). If you want to program or use that software, you should install Ubuntu MATE on a separate partition on your host. There is an option for this during installation. Just remember to backup any data from the VM!